# How to Access Audio File URL from Child Component in Parent Component in Vue.js and firebase storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I'm building a Vue.js application where users can create playlists and add songs to them. I am having some issues with these two components: AddSong.vue for and uploading album covers and audio file, and PlaylistDetails.vue for displaying playlist information and songs.

in AddSong, i could upload the audio file to firebase storage and verify that it is indeed present in the directory.

```js
export default {
    props: ['playlist', 'audioFile'],
  setup(props) {
    //setting up some refs
    const audioFile = ref(null);

    const {update_doc} = use_doc('playlists', props.playlist.id);

// uploadfile to Firebase storage, retrieve its download URLupload and return the ref to filePath, url, etc
    const { upload, url, filePath } = useStorage(); 

    const handleFileChange = (event) => 
    {
      audioFile.value = event.target.files[0];// Get the selected audio file from the input
    }

    const handleUpload = async () => {
      if (audioFile.value) {
        try {
          await upload(audioFile.value); 
          
          console.log('Audio file URL:', url.value);
          console.log('Audio file Path is:', filePath.value);
          
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error uploading audio file:', error.message);
        }
      
    };
    
//some methods irrelevant methods like handleSubmit i cropped it out the question
    return { title, artist, show, handleSubmit, handleFileChange, handleUpload, audioFile }

  }
}
</script>
```

but, although **I have returned audioFile as props, I can not seems to access it in this playlistDetails class:**

```
import AddSong from '@/components/AddSong.vue'

export default
 {
    components: {AddSong},
    props: ['id', 'playlist', 'audioFile'],
    setup(props)
    {
    //some methods to handle click function etc
    }
}
`<template>
 <p> {{audioFile.url}} <p>  <!-- i tried to print the url to website to verify but it is null -->
</template>`
```

useStorage.js: Its initially use for image files but it also work on audio files

```
import { projectStorage } from "@/firebase/config";
import { ref } from "vue";
import getUser from "./getUser";

const {user} = getUser(); //get the user object from getUser.js

const  useStorage =() =>
{
    const error = ref(null);
    const url = ref(null);
    const filePath = ref(null);

    const upload = async (file) => {
        filePath.value = `covers/${user.value.uid}/${file.name}`; 
        const storageRef = projectStorage.ref(filePath.value);
    
        try {
            const uploadTask = await storageRef.put(file);
            url.value = await uploadTask.ref.getDownloadURL(); // Await the URL retrieval
           
        } catch (err) {
          
        }
    };
    
    return {url, filePath, error, upload}
}

export default useStorage
```

To summarise, the question is: How can I access the audio file URL from AddSong.vue in PlaylistDetails.vue so I can add the songs' URLs to the playlist? I feel like I am missing something very obvious but I just can not figure it out.
I would really appreciate any suggestions or help!

Comment: Have a look at the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#full_example): You need to call the `getDownloadURL()` method in order to get the URL.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec . Thank you for your suggestion. However, the url has already been retrieved through the useStorage method. ` . I have edited the post to include the useStorage method. I would appreciate it if you could look into the issue again.

Comment: So I understand that `console.log('Audio file URL:', url.value);` prints the correct value.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec thats the strange part, it prints out null :). The logic seems to be correct but the code is not working as intended

Comment: I guess you should debug your `useStorage.js` method.